# Forward one Fragment to another Fragment in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, kotlin, onclicklistener

I have Two Fragments in my main activity. If I click one Fragment item then it need to move to another next fragment. If Its activity to activity then I can use intent and if it is related to fragment then I am not sure. Any help is appreciated.

**Language Used**

```
Kotlin
```

**Fragments**

```
OneFragement----->SecondFragment
```

**Code**

**Adapter Class**

```
itemView.setOnClickListener {

            Log.d("Test Clicked","Test Clicked")
        }
```

**FragmentOne**

```
val ft = fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
    ft.replace(R.id.Two, SecondFragment(), "NewFragmentTag")
    ft.commit()
```

Comment: is fragment transaction not working for you what is the problem explain that?

Comment: Its not working and getting null pointer exception.

Comment: Null pointer at what line share the error log

Comment: If you look into my question, I asked suggestion from people. I mentioned that I am not sure about forwarding one fragment to another.

Comment: `it need to move to another next fragment` this means u need fragment transaction

Answer (score 0):

In **MainActivity**

```
fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment, tag: String) {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag).addToBackStack("").commit()
}
```

In **FragmentTwo**

```
class FragmentTwo:Fragment(){

 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
   //your  code
}
 companion object {
    val TAG = FragmentTwo::class.java.simpleName
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance() = FragmentTwo()
  }
}
```

In **FragmentOne**

```
class FragmentOne:Fragment(){

 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
   //your  code
}

fun onItemSelected(){
    val frag=FragmentTwo.newInstance()
    (activity as MainActivity).replaceFragment(frag,FragmentTwo.TAG)
}
 companion object {
    val TAG = FragmentOne::class.java.simpleName
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance() = FragmentOne()
  }
}
```

**In AdapterClass**:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener{
    frag.onItemSelected()
}
```

Comment: For further info you can refer to my answer on your other post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53982139/fragment-onclick-listener/53983939#53983939)