# Fragment Onclick Listener

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin, android-fragmentactivity

I am using Bottom Navigation Activity in my project. Which contains following activities. I am using kotlin Language. I am not sure how to route from one fragment to another fragment in bottom navigation activity. Any help is appreciated.

**Code:**

```
https://github.com/joshvapeter/KotlinBottomNavigationNew
```

**Activies**

```
1)One Main Activity 
2)Two Fragments
3)Two Adapter Class
4)Two Layout files
```

**Expectation**

When I click the Fragment One Recycler View Item then It need to automatically route it to Fragment two Recycler View Item in the next bottom tab. Below is the code, I am using in my project.

**Code**

**Fragment One Adapter**

```
        itemView.setOnClickListener {

           Log.d("Fragment One Clicked","Fragment One Clicked")
            //FragmentTwo()

            }
```

**MainActivity**

```
fun ShowFragmentOne() {
    val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
    val fragment = FragmentOne()
    transaction.replace(R.id.one, fragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
    isFragmentOneLoaded = true
}

fun ShowFragmentTwo() {
    val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
    val fragment = FragmentTwo()
    transaction.replace(R.id.two, fragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
    isFragmentOneLoaded = false
}
```

Comment: It's better if you omit the parts not related to the question from the code snippet, like all the empty lifecycle methods

Comment: best use viewmodel concepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment. So on the basis of my understanding, i am writing this answer. If my understanding is wrong, please comment.

From what i can understand you want to move to FragmentTwo when an item is clicked in RecyclerView in FragmentOne. You can achieve it in following way:

**FragmentOne**:

```
fun onItemSelected(item:MyModel){
    (activity as MainActivity).showFragmentTwo(item)
}
```

**FragmentOneAdapter**:

```
class FragmentOneAdapter(val fragment:FragmentOne,val myList:ArrayList<MyModel>):RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>(){
override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): MyViewHolder {
    //your code to create view holder
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: MyViewHolder, p1: Int) {
    p0.bindItem(myList[p1], fragment)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return myList.size
}

class MyViewHolder(view:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    fun bindItem(item:MyModel,frag:FragmentOne)=with(itemView){
        setOnClickListener{
            frag.onItemSelected(item)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ankuranurag2 for your comment and you are right but I am getting error while using the above code. Can we have a chat? please let me know.

Comment: sure lets have a chat.

Comment: Also you can provide the code snippet  where you are facing the issue.

Comment: I have added rough diagram in my question. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: If I add frag.onItemSelected(item) in my fragment then I am getting error because this method doesn't exist.

Comment: The FragmnetOne and Fragmenttwo in the diagram's bottom are buttons, right?

Comment: This is I am getting from menu

Comment: frag.onItemSelected(item) has to be written in Adapter class. Please see the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185964/discussion-between-ankuranurag2-and-josh-jo).

Comment: Code used in my project is something similar to this one.  https://github.com/skooltch84/bottomNavigationWithFragmentsKotlin

Comment: Write the 'onItemSelected()' method in your FragmentOne and call this method from Adapter's ` itemView.setOnClickListener{}`.

Comment: I have uploaded the code in https://github.com/joshvapeter/KotlinBottomNavigationNew